# how to run code sequentially in node js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Hi I have this code but when finish the result is not the espected because didn't run in the sequence that I wish

here is the code:

```
var user_data = {};    
models.games.find({$or: [{w_id: req.user._id}, {b_id: req.user._id}, {owner: req.user._id}]}, function (err, games) {
        var req_games = [];
        if (!err) {
            for (var i in games) {
                req_games.push(games[i]);
                models.users.findOne({_id: games[i].w_id}, function (err, user) {
                    req_games[i].w_id = user.user;
                    console.log(req_games[i].w_id) //< -- 3
                });
                console.log('a ' + req_games[i].w_id) //<-- 2
            }
            user_data.games = req_games; //  <-- 1
        }
    });
```

at the end of the task `req_games` didnt have any update because it's running in the sequence that I put in the comments in the code

Comment: You need to read up on how callbacks work in Javascript - this is by design, it's asynchronous. It takes a bit of getting used to. What are you trying to do after your `user_data.games = req_games` call?

Comment: after that `res.render('user.swig', {user: user_data});` its a express web application and its rendering wrong the results, I know that is because the asynchronous task running but I'm new with node and  don't know how to deal with this situation

Comment: what's the purpose of the for loop? I can't tell why you're looping over the found games array

Comment: because I need to change the `w_id` of each game for the user name of this id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library to map your game values.

```
var async = require('async');

var user_data = {};  
models.games.find({$or: [{w_id: req.user._id}, {b_id: req.user._id}, {owner: req.user._id}]}, function (err, games) {
  if(err) {
    // or whatever your error response happens to be
    return res.render('user.swig', {error: err});
  }

  async.map(games, function(game, nextGame) {
    models.users.findOne({_id: game.w_id}, function (err, user) {
      game.w_id = user.user;
      nextGame(err, game);
    });
  }, function(err, req_games) {
    user_data.games = req_games;
    res.render('user.swig', {user: user_data});
  });
});
```

Comment: It would be more efficient, but adds quite a bit of complexity and you still have to loop. In fact, now you have to loop even more since you need to map the gameIds, and then map the users array back to the games array.  Depending on how many games I expected to be returned, this isn't necessarily an "optimization" I would make. It would look something like this: http://pastebin.com/VTGuMkjm

Answer (score 2):

This may help you using Q(promises)

```
obj.find = function(model, condition) {  //make your find to return promise
        var deferred = q.defer();
        model.find(condition, function(err, results) {
          if (err) {
            logger.log(err);
            deferred.reject(err);
          } else {
            deferred.resolve(results);
          }
        });
        return deferred.promise;
      }


     ArraysOfId.forEach(function (id) {
          var tempProm = mongoUtilsMethodObj.find(schemaObj.Asset, id).then(function (assetObj) {
            ---- your code

            return q.resolve();
          });
          promArr.push(tempProm);//push all promise to array
        });

        q.all(promArr).then(function () {
         // this will be called when all promise in array will we resolved


          })
```